# Firebase Active User Drop Off After App Update

Tags: ios, firebase-analytics

But realtime traffic users are still appearing and latest release shows that users are adopting the new version, so clearly it's still reporting correctly? But all of the data dropped to 0 overnight. Any ideas?

Comment: There is not enough information here for anyone to say anything meaningful. If the data doesn't recover automatically, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, as they can have a look at your project's data, which may show what's going on.

Comment: I'm seeing the same for android app. Every update roll-out there is drop in "active users" presented by Firebase Analytics.
When I check same kind of analytics I do by my own (Analytics exported to BigQuery + Data Studio) - Everything is fine.

Comment: Experiencing similar on ios, after update gets released, dau drops the next day